# How to mix in musical background while speaking in a Google-hangout?

Tags: audio, google-hangouts

I use Google Hangouts to make an online radio broadcast. I would like to add some music to my voice during the broadcast (insert a jingle, etc.).

How can I transmit the audio input of both the microphone as well any audio track I play from the PC itself? (Note: This may be called Stereo Mix on some devices)

Answer (score 3):

You need to output sound to the recipient from both your microphone AND your computer. Ordinarily, you can only do one or the other. There are **two options** to accomplish transmitting them simultaneously:

1. You can use **Stereo Mix** if your sound driver (and sound card) supports it. Instructions to enable it (if at all possible) can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/).
2. If Stereo Mix is not an option for your computer, you can download **[VoiceMeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter)** and/or **[Virtual Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/VirtualCables.htm)**.
   These two downloads are both from a company called VB-Audio. The downloads are called "donation-ware", meaning you should donate, but the downloads are technically free. Instructions for using each of these products is on the website. For example, the manual for VoiceMeeter can be found [here](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf).

Good luck!